# Can I ride on the Gatwick monorail after bag-drop/check in?

Tags: airports, airport-terminals

I'm flying from Gatwick for the first time next week with a train nerd son. We are flying from the North Terminal. After we've dropped our bags (have checked in online already) can we ride the monorail to the South Terminal and back to kill time/entertain ourselves?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can see on the terminal maps at http://www.gatwickairport.com/at-the-airport/passenger-services/airport-maps/ where the shuttle runs, you can use it after you check in but it is before security so make sure to leave enough time for your flight. I also feel the need to point out that the shuttle technicaly isn't a monorail, not to get tool technical it has rubber ties on a concrete track.

Comment: Thanks. It is described as a monorail somewhere, I think on their website somewhere. Plan B: could we ride it before going through security? I mean, is there a check of tickets/boarding passes to ensure you're entitled to be on it?

Comment: My personal experiance with this is now a few years old but certainly there wasn't any check. Iv failed to find an aurthorative source for this but I belive it still to be the case. https://www.gatwickreservations.com/terminal/monorail states that "You don't need to stay overnight right next to the terminal you are flying from. For example, you can stay at the South Terminal Hilton hotel even if you are flying from the North Terminal. Simply catch the monorail over to the North Terminal in the morning." This wouldn't be possible if there was some sort of check. Coloquily it's called a monorail

Comment: I've ridden it much more recently, there is definitely no check, or any requirement to have a ticket or boarding pass.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can ride it after checking in, as long as you've not gone through security. There are no checks or controls, so anyone can freely board it and ride back and forth as much as they like (within reason - bear in mind that security is heightened at the moment, so they might stop you if they think you are acting in a suspicious manner)

Also, you don't mention which airline you are flying with, but if it's Easyjet, allow extra time to get through security and to the gate, as many of their flights go from an 'annex' which is a fairly long walk (700m according to the airport website) from the main part of the north terminal.